# Python Port Listener (Like NC)

Tags: python

So I would like to make a Python port listener that resembles Netcat (nc -l -v -p 2121). I have looked around and haven't been able to find what I am looking for. I just want to be able to give a port via a CLI argument and listen on that port (python listen.py 2121). If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The place to start from will be the [`socket`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) module (which is a builtin).

To set up a listening socket `s`, you would do something like:

```
port = 1234

s = socket.socket()
s.bind(("", port))
s.listen(1)
```

Once the socket is listening, you can accept a connection on it using `socket.accept()`, which will return a tuple containing the connected socket and the address it connected from.

Comment: Great answer. But note that if you want `nc -kl` rather than just `nc -l`, you'll need some kind of concurrency, whether an event loop (e.g., around `select`) or firing off a background thread for each `accept`. Also, if you want to be able to read from `stdin` as well as the socket (as `nc` does), you already need concurrency even just for `nc -l`.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [SocketServer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html) module, there are lots of examples there.

Answer (score 0):

import os

def run_netcat_listener(port):
# Run netcat listener using os.system
os.system(f'nc -l -p {port}')

## Specify the port to listen on

port = 1234

## Run the netcat listener

run_netcat_listener(port)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).